# Spring Boot JPA search matches for all non null values

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is there an easy way to populate some of the fields of an entity and tell spring to return all the entities in the repository matching all the non-null values?

Example:

```
Jacket jacket = new Jacket();
jacket.setColor("blue");
jacket.setSize("XL");
Pocket pocket= new Pocket();
pocket.setShape("round");
pocket.setType("open");
jacket.setPocket(pocket);
Set<Jacket> matchingJackets = jacketRepository.findAllLike(jacket);
```

Where `Jacket` and `Pocket` are `@Entity` and `jacketRepository` is the autogenerated repo for `public interface JacketRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<Jacket, UUID>`

(Take on account I am not looking for a solution to this specific case, but all cases, if for example I don't `pocket.setShape("someshape");` it should return all matching jackets without looking at the pocket shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Query by example feature of spring-data-jpa

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#query-by-example